# How can I see my contributions on GitHub to everywhere except my own repo's?

Tags: github

I want to see all [contributions](https://github.com/hak8or?tab=activity) I made to others on GitHub, but I do a ton of work in my own repositories so my contributions tab has my commits to my repo's overshadowing my contributions to others.

Would it be possible to basically see all my contributions exclude things like me starring other projects and contributions to my own repositories?

Comment: https://github.com/ghuser-io/github-contribs

Answer (score 12):

At the moment, there is no way to do this on github.com. The closest feature may be searching for pull requests and issues:

If you go in the [Pull request tab](https://github.com/pulls?q=author%3A%40me+-user%3A%40me) and search for `author:@me -user:@me`, you will have a list of contributions (only pull requests and issues opened) made to repositories you do not own.

Comment: In addition, if you only want include contributions on public repositories, you can add `is:public` to the search query.

Answer (score 9):

**Update:** Looks like this only returns:

> A list of repositories that the user **recently** contributed to.

I guess "recently" means 1 year.

Also, it only selects up to 100 repositories at a time.

---

You can use the following GraphQL query in the [API Explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/):

```
query getContributions($login: String!, $contributionTypes: [RepositoryContributionType]) {
  user(login: $login) {
    repositoriesContributedTo(contributionTypes: $contributionTypes, first: 100, includeUserRepositories: false, orderBy: {field: STARGAZERS, direction: DESC}) {
      pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
        endCursor
      }
      nodes {
        nameWithOwner
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Put this in query variables (replace login with your own user id) and then execute.

```
{
  "login": "zypA13510",
  "contributionTypes": [
    "COMMIT",
    "REPOSITORY"
  ]
}
```

The list of valid `contributionTypes`:

> COMMIT
> Created a commit
>
> ISSUE
> Created an issue
>
> PULL_REQUEST
> Created a pull request
>
> REPOSITORY
> Created the repository
>
> PULL_REQUEST_REVIEW
> Reviewed a pull request

Comment: Thanks for this. I was able to get the repo names by doing an HTTP POST to `https://api.github.com/graphql` with the following request body: ```{"query":"{user(login:\"your_github_username\") {    repositoriesContributedTo(contributionTypes: [COMMIT, REPOSITORY], last: 100, includeUserRepositories: false) { pageInfo { startCursor hasPreviousPage } nodes { owner { login } name }}}}"}```