# How many GitHub projects have merged my pull requests?

Tags: github

I often send pull requests to various GitHub projects, and often they merge them.

For narcissistic reasons, I want to know how many projects contain some of my changes.

Does GitHub have any such feature, or offer any other way to know that number?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/pulls has your pull request history. I'm not sure how to use the site to only show one per repo if you've contributed multiple times to the same repo though.

Comment: Currently I [don't think](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/74699/140514) there is a way to show all of your GitHub contributions. It is likely possible with the GitHub API though.